# RadGrid trying to keep insert form open after insert

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik radgrid which is a basic data entry form.

I want to keep the insert form open after an insert.
The user clicks the insert button, the record saves, the grid is still in insert mode.

I can get the grid to open in insert mode by using

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = true;
```

However, no matter where I put this code (page_prerender, oninsert,etc.), when the record is inserted the radgrid goes back to viewing the grid items. I tried to do it client side after load ($(document).ready) but that code doesn't get called.(Probably due to the radajaxmanager overriding it)

```
   var grid = $find("<%#RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
        grid.get_masterTableView().IsItemInserted = true;
```

Does anyone know how to keep the insert row template open after an insert?

My next step to is keep a few of the values from the previous insert, so if you know how to do that to please include that.

Comment: Please set below property.

AllowAutomaticInserts="true"

Answer (score 1):

You can set **e.Canceled = true;** in your itemCommand event

Answer (score 0):

You can use next:

```
<Telerik:RadGrid ID="Grid"
    OnNeedDataSource="NeedDataSource" ..>
```

NeedDataSource function:

```
protected void NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e) {
  parametersGrid.DataSource = data;
  parametersGrid.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = true;
}
```